# Catch unhandled exception and stop method?

Tags: c#

In a windows form application, `List<>` of class will be checked by method and its return type is bool.

Example if there are 100 classes and just 1 class returns `false` then it's another field(`Reqbool`) will be `fals`e. Only `Reqbool` will be `true` when all classes got `true` return.

Is there any easy way to solve this? It says exception is unhandled and each `false` return it shows messagebox.

```
bool Reqbool = true;
bool MiniReqbool;
if(MiniReqbool == false) { throw new Exception(); }
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ImportList.Count; i++)
    {
        MiniMiniTest mitest = new MiniMiniTest();
        MiniReqbool = mitest.ReqTest(ImportList[i], QValue);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Reqbool = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry points not found");
}
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear, that may be a language barrier. I think you're looking for `Enumerable.All()` or `Enumerable.Any()` but I cant tell.

Comment: So if `mitest.ReqTest` returns `false` for any item in `ImportList` you want `Reqbool` to be `false`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yes absolutely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set `Reqbool` to `false` only if all the items in `ImportList` return `true` for `mitest.ReqTest`. In that case you can use Linq and the extension method `All`:

```
MiniMiniTest mitest = new MiniMiniTest();
Reqbool = ImportList.All(il => mitest.ReqTest(il, QValue));
```

If you want a new `MiniMiniTest` per item you can use the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ImportList.Count; i++)
{
    MiniMiniTest mitest = new MiniMiniTest();
    if (!mitest.ReqTest(ImportList[i], QValue))
    {
        Reqbool = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or use a `foreach` loop to make it simpler:

```
foreach (var item in ImportList) //...
```

---

Side note the following code:

```
bool MiniReqbool;
if(MiniReqbool == false) { throw new Exception(); }
```

Will always throw the exception as a `bool` has a default value of `false` so I assume this isn't your actual code.

Comment: I do think your side note is his actual code, he mentions something like "It says exception is unhandled", that is exactly what would happen if you place the throw before the catch.

Answer (score 2):

You throw your exception before the try catch. If you place the if statement after your check, it should be fixed.

```
bool Reqbool = true;
bool MiniReqbool;

try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ImportList.Count; i++)
    {
        MiniMiniTest mitest = new MiniMiniTest();
        MiniReqbool = mitest.ReqTest(ImportList[i], QValue);
        if(MiniReqbool == false) { throw new Exception(); }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Reqbool = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry points not found");
}
```

As suggested in the comments it's better to do this without exceptions, which can still be done in the same way you are working like this.

```
bool Reqbool = true;
bool MiniReqbool = true;

for (int i = 0; i < ImportList.Count; i++)
{
    MiniMiniTest mitest = new MiniMiniTest();
    if(!mitest.ReqTest(ImportList[i], QValue)) { MiniReqbool = false; }
}
if (MiniReqbool == false)
{
    Reqbool = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry points not found");
}
```

Comment: True, I will update my answer a bit for a way without exceptions